# Git sed.exe uname.exe problems

Tags: git, zurb-foundation, git-bash

I just Installed Git 1.8.5.2
My OS - Windows 7 home premium

Everytime I open Git Bash.
It show me the following error messages

- sed.exe has stopped working.
- uname.exe has stopped working.

Anyone having this issue?
How to fix it?

This happened after I delete my Foundation 5 scss project. The project was created by using Git bash.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to fixed this problem by temporarily deactivating Comodo Antivirus. I assume it blocked Git Bash. Maybe you have similar problem with your antivirus.